# Unable to connect to ec2 instance using putty

Tags: putty, amazon-ec2

I am connecting to the ec2 instance Amazon Linux AMI via putty and getting the error

Server Refused our key

Please provide a solution for this

Comment: We need a like more information here, like whether on not you used PuTTYgen for the key, what steps you took, and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have the right key. If you created it during the instance launch AWS Console will prompt you to download it.
2. Putty won't work with the standard PEM keys. Convert the key from PEM format to the Putty's own format.
3. Make sure you've set the correct user name in Putty. For Amazon Linux it's `ec2-user` by default.